# После восстановления файловой системы Linux, не сохраняются системные настройки

Tags: linux, файловая-система, linux-mint

Имеется Linux Mint 19 Cinnamon. Произошел сбой файловой системы `xfs`, корневой раздел перестал монтироваться, а утилита `xfs_repair` не могла найти суперблоки и журнал. Файловая система все таки была восстановлена с помощью запуска `xfs_repair -L`, но после загрузки обнаружил, что не сохраняются системные настройки. В частности не отключается сенсорную панель на ноутбуке. Другие настройки тоже не сохраняются. Не сохраняются настройки некоторых приложений, например в редакторе `xed` устанавливаю показывать номера строк, но после закрытия и открытия номера пропадают. Еще обнаружил обновлений пакетов на ~500 Мб. Какая может быть причина?

Comment: *Не сохраняются настройки некоторых приложений* - проверьте, может быть в Вашем домашнем каталоге просто пропала папка *~/.config* ? Или права на неё изменились каким-то нехорошим образом...

Comment: Она есть, права вроде в порядке. Мне кажется в ней недостаточно файлов. Например здесь /home/mint/.config/cinnamon-session/saved-session пустой каталог. Есть способы ее восстановить?

Comment: Удаление каталога ~/.config не принесло результата.